# How to allow a port to accept connection from all external ip adresses?

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I have just started using Linux.
My `OS` details are following.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I want to accept `TCP` connections from all external IP address on port 8086 so that all external clients have access to `INFLUXDB` database running on the server on the same port. I have tried several things available without having any luck. I have tried

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8086 -j ACCEPT
```

The output of the `iptables -L` looks something like:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I check whether port is open for external IP using telnet, I got the following output:

```
$ telnet 103.65.xx.xxx 8086
Trying 103.65.xx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Also, It is not showing up in listening ports. I want to make it one similar to port 5432 for `POSTGRESQL`

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1488/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      94889/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1074/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1488/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      94889/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      3858/node /usr/shar
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      3945/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      3945/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3945/java
```

How can I open the port on all external client IP?

**P.S.** I don't want to use `ufw`utility. Any other help apart from this is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're actually using Ubuntu - I'd apply security upgrades & fixes to your system asap, as your provided details imply a system that hasn't had upgrades applied since [Feb-2020](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/) as that's when 18.04.4 was released, installed systems upgrading to it weeks before then too; and a fully-upgraded system will report as [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) again the date reflecting the ISO release date; installed systems upgrading before that date.  Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I want to achieve with the current settings? I don't have privilege to change any settings or upgrade it because server belong to one of client and I only want to establish the connection to their influx database.

Comment: Your iptables policy is ACCEPT, so all ports are allowed to connect by default. You don't need any special rule. Your actual problem is that your service is NOT actually listening on port 8086, as your netstat output shows. You have to debug that. Are you sure the service is running? Are you sure it is configured to use that port?

Comment: You should ask the client to fix their system and bring it up-to-date before mucking about with your work. If their system is compromised or broken, then your work will be wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the firewall or network setting. Your system is able to listen on all TCP ports. But it looks your INFLUXDB service is not running and listening.

To check the service status try this:

```
sudo systemctl status influxdb
```

In case you see some errors in the status you should solve them.

Service starting:

```
sudo systemctl start influxdb
```

Last logs after unsuccessful start can be displayed by the `sudo journalctl -xe` and `tail -n 100 /var/log/dmesg` or `sudo dmesg` commands.

Your test using `netstat` command is the right way to check open ports. But the influxdb service must be started before it.